# Keep focus in command window when debugging MATLAB

Tags: debugging, matlab, ide

Often in MATLAB I turn on 'automatic' debugging with `dbstop if error`.  When an error occurs, the function enters debug mode, and I am able to query the variables in the command window and see exactly what is going on. Very useful.

However, when this occurs, the focus switches to the editor. To me this seems counter-intuitive; we are in debug mode, so I want to find out what is going on, not look at the code (which I can already see in the adjacent window). I always immediately tab back to the command window.

**So my first question is:** Is there any point in accessing the editor at this point? What can I usefully *do*, when my script has crashed, in the editor?

**And secondly:** If I want to, can I change MATLAB's default behaviour to keep the focus in the command window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your second question:

If you use MATLAB's desktop environment, just deselect "Open Files when Debugging" in the "Debug" menu.

If you use MATLAB without the graphical desktop you can change this preference by modifying your `matlab.prf` file. This file stores preferences set from the GUI. The menu option described above makes the same changes as the manual process described below.

**NOTE: Editing this file is entirely unsupported. Do so at your own risk.**

1. Open the file from the MATLAB command prompt,

   `>> edit([prefdir '/matlab.prf'])`

   Or use the `prefdir` command in MATLAB to find the directory and then open the file in whatever editor you prefer.
2. Search for a line that says

   `EditorGraphicalDebugging=Btrue`
3. Change it to read

   `EditorGraphicalDebugging=Bfalse`

   If the line doesn't exist, add it to the file.
4. Restart MATLAB.

Comment: To simplify this a bit, you can use Matlab's internal java method to set this preference programmatically: `com.mathworks.services.Prefs.setBooleanPref('EditorGraphicalDebugging',false)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the invocation stack to see how you came about to the particular error position. Sure, you can use `dbup` and `dbdown` for this in the command window, but it's much easier in the editor.

Also, seeing the variables (and their values, using mouse hover) in the context of the code that caused the crash is far better for understanding the root cause of the error than just seeing the static values.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer only your first question.

Things you can do in the editor:

- Mouse hover a variable, which pops up a 'quick view' window.
- Any action you can do when not in debug mode, treating the function as a script - running a line (highlight + F9), running a code block, etc.